# Convert to outlines not working in Acrobat

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, adobe-acrobat

I have this PDF that I have converted the fonts to outlines but when I open it in Illustrator I still get a missing font error. Everything looks to check out in Acrobat. Before I apply convert to outlines, under Document Properties>Fonts, there are fonts listed. And after I apply convert to outlines there are no fonts listed. So I'm not sure why I'm getting this error in Illustrator. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you save the file?

Comment: Yes I did. I wish it was something that simple haha

Comment: Did you have all fonts? The missing one can't be converted.

Comment: I do not have the particular font I'm getting an error from when I open the PDF in Illustrator. So even though it appears correctly in Acrobat and its not listed under Docment Properties>Fonts after I run "convert fonts to outlines"--it wont be outlined because I don't have the font? I feel like I've been able to outline fonts in Acrobat before even if i didnt have them. Maybe I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little workaround that works in the newest version of Acrobat. You basically "trick" the program into outlining fonts you don't have installed on your computer by adding a transparent watermark before creating outlines through the flattener preview.

---

1. Navigate to **Tools > Edit PDF > Add Watermark**:

[image]

2. In the Add Watermark options panel, ***add watermark text*** (anything you'd like), ***change the position*** of the watermark so it doesn't interfere with any of the graphics you want to keep, and ***change the opacity of the watermark to 0%***:

[image]

[image]

3. Navigate to **Tools > Print Production > Flattener Preview**:

[image]

4. In the Flattener Preview options panel tick the ***Convert All Text to Outlines*** box, click ***Apply***, and then click ***Ok***:

[image]

5. ***Save the PDF*** and open in Illustrator:

[image]

*^ In outline mode, you can see that the watermark text is still present. Just select and delete the watermark, save, and you should be all set.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I eventually found that myself and used it as my solution. Do you know....even though it appears correctly in Acrobat and its not listed under Docment Properties>Fonts after I run "convert fonts to outlines"--it wont be outlined because I don't have the font? I feel like I've been able to outline fonts in Acrobat before even if i didnt have them. Maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that answer (even though it would seem that process would be the more intuitive option). My best guess is  since you don't have the font installed, there's not sufficient data to reference in converting the font to outlines.

Comment: Yeah you would think if it the convert works in the flattener preview--it would also work by using the convert text to outlines fix up. Thanks for the response!